# How to count number of items in .csv in Python?

Tags: python

I have a simple .csv

```
Product name
orange
banana
orange
pizza
```

in Python I would like to get a list of unique items but the double items should be counted, like +1. So in this case: Orange 2

How can I do this? Here is my code:

```
import argparse
import csv
from collections import Counter
from datetime import date

# Do not modify these lines
__winc_id__ = 'a2bc36ea784242e4989deb157d527ba0'
__human_name__ = 'superpy'

# Add your code after this line

# read requested input from file csv file
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("inputfile", help="Geef de te lezen .csv input file op")

args = parser.parse_args()
with open(args.inputfile) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    unique_products = []
    count = 0
    
    for item in reader:
            
        if item not in unique_products:
                       
            unique_products.append(item) 

            count += 1     


    print(unique_products, count)
```

Now the result is:

```
[{'Product name': 'orange'}, {'Product name': 'banana'}, {'Product name': 'pizza'}] 3
```

I would like to have the product and after it the number of products

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
unique_products = dict()
    count = 0
    
    for item in reader:
            
        if item not in unique_products.keys():
                       
            unique_products[item] = 1
    else:
    unique_products[item] += 1
    enter code here


   


    print(unique_products)
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already imported `Counter` from `collections` so just use it!

The unique thing about `Counter` class is that you don't get an error when referencing a key that is not in the dictionary.
You can treat it as if all possible keys have already been inserted and initialized to value of 0.

```
unique_products = Counter()

for item in reader:
    unique_products[item] += 1

print(f"{unique_products} {len(uniqie_products)}")
```